# Table Of Contents Title In Uppercase Letters

Tags: table-of-contents

I have generated a Table of Contents in a document and I would like to make the title "Contents" in uppercase letters, i.e. "CONTENTS". All I have found searching was how to customize the entries in the table and not the title. How can this be done?

I work in ShareLaTeX with `XeLaTeX` and my full preamble is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage
[   
    top=0.7in,
    bottom=1.2in,
    left=0.8in,
    right=0.8in,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont
[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*,
    BoldFont=*Bold,
    ItalicFont=*It,
    BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
    Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{mdframed}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally `touhami's` solution should work, but the special `babel` settings prevent his solution.

In this case, the redefinition of the `\contentsname` should be shifted after `\begin{document}` -- this can be done with `\AtBeginDocument{...}`.

Another possibility should be the `\addto...` way. I'll try to provide this as well.

Alternatively, say

```
\selectlanguage{greek}
\let\mtcontentsname\contentsname
\addto\captionsgreek{\typeout{foo}\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\mtcontentsname}}
```

in the preamble.

I believe, using `polyglossia` is the better variant in conjunction with `XeLaTeX` instead of `babel`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage
[   
    top=0.7in,
    bottom=1.2in,
    left=0.8in,
    right=0.8in,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont
[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*,
    BoldFont=*Bold,
    ItalicFont=*It,
    BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
    Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}

\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\mtcontentsname\contentsname
  \renewcommand\contentsname{\MakeUppercase\mtcontentsname}
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly the same as before. There is no problem but not any result either... :/

Comment: @Adam: Well, you should only a preamble, but **not** anything shortly after the `\begin{document}`. Either there is the culprit or some other setting is completely wrong. Hard to tell without any code

Comment: Ok then as you have checked that this works I believe that it will work for me too eventually. Thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Here is

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\mtcontentsname\contentsname
\renewcommand\contentsname{\MakeUppercase\mtcontentsname}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything... :/

Comment: @Adam: If touhami's solution does not work for you because you have a peculiar setup you should provide more information.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I provided my full setup.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to steal the tick

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to patch `\tableofcontents` so that it prints the title uppercase:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \patchcmd

\setmainfont[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*,
    BoldFont=*Bold,
    ItalicFont=*It,
    BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
    Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{ενότητα τίτλο}

\subsection{ενότητα τίτλο}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use

```
\addto\captionsgreek{%
  \edef\contentsname{%
    \noexpand\MakeUppercase{\unexpanded\expandafter{\contentsname}}%
  }%
}
```

and similarly if you need it for English.

The uppercasing you want is *formatting*, rather than redefining fixed labels, so the `\patchcmd` method is better suited. However, it can become complicated if you need to patch several commands.

In this case the `\addto` method might be preferable and we can provide an  abstraction. For instance, let's suppose you also want the list of figures and tables to have uppercased title and also the name for the abstract; the last one should be available in uppercase for both Greek and English.

```
\newcommand{\upcasebabellabel}[1]{%
  \edef#1{\noexpand\MakeUppercase{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}}%
}

\addto\captionsgreek{%
  \upcasebabellabel\contentsname
  \upcasebabellabel\listfigurename
  \upcasebabellabel\listtablename
  \upcasebabellabel\abstractname
}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \upcasebabellabel\abstractname
}
```