# how to make title of tableofcontents and references uppercase with xelatex, polyglossia, koma script

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, polyglossia

I am using xelatex polyglossia and koma script package. I appreciate if someone can show me how to make title of tableofcontents and references to uppercase, as in Contents to CONTENTS, References to REFERECES.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{headings=small,numbers=endperiod}
\KOMAoption{toc}{bibnumbered,chapterentrywithdots} 

\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{turkish} 
\setotherlanguages{english}

\usepackage{blindtext} 

\begin{document}

\newpage
  \tableofcontents
\newpage

\blinddocument

bla, bla, bla\cite{babcock_models_2002} 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I appreciate any help. I am a newbie so please bare with me...

Comment: @user1155710: The code you posted is not compilable (put `biblatex`and `\addbibresource` at the end of your preamble to remove the error messages) and does still not produce a table of contents. Apart from that, what do you mean with "resourses"? Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLySM.png)  what you want to achieve?

Comment: [Table Of Contents Title In Uppercase Letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/293919/134144) might be useful.

Comment: Thank for the comment leandriis.  I have seen that post previously. Provided solutions were using babel. I tried sevaral of them did not work in my case. I did not like the patching method...There should be more clear way to do it. I do not understand or suprized why it is so weird, difficult to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If uppercase is only needed for the TOC and bibliography title:

```latex
\documentclass[titlepage,12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{headings=small,numbers=endperiod}
\KOMAoption{toc}{
  %bibnumbered,% not needed because of the own \bibheading
  chapterentrywithdots}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{turkish} 
\setotherlanguages{english}

\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*\tableofcontents
  {\listoftoc[{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}]{toc}}
\defbibheading{uppercasetitle}[\MakeUppercase{\bibname}]
  {\chapter{#1}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
bla, bla, bla\cite{springer} 
\printbibliography[heading=uppercasetitle]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If all chapter titles should be uppercase

```latex
\documentclass[titlepage,12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{headings=small,numbers=endperiod}
\KOMAoption{toc}{bibnumbered,chapterentrywithdots} 

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{turkish} 
\setotherlanguages{english}

\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\let\originalchapterlinesformat\chapterlinesformat
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}}
    {\originalchapterlinesformart{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}
\let\originaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand\addchaptertocentry[2]{%
  \originaladdchaptertocentry{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
bla, bla, bla\cite{springer} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, esdd. Thank you for the reply. I can confirm that, \renewcommand*\tableofcontents ... works but   \defbibheading{uppercasetitle} does not. I have to change to uppercase title to bibliography by looking at the biblatex documantation. As far as I understand the bibliography in \defbibheading{bibliography} is a keyword for selection a specific behaviour. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @user1155710 In my first example `\printbibliography[heading=uppercasetitle]* was missing. I have added the missing code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "uppercasetitle" in \defbibheading{uppercasetitle}[\MakeUppercase{\bibname}] {\chapter{#1}} to "bibliography" or something else stated in the definition of \defbibheading in biblatex documentation. There options which could be used. The solution with the change of uppercasetitle to bibliography works perfectly for my case...