# Uppercase Title on ToC, LoF, and LoT

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, book-class

I want to change the title on ToC, LoF, and LoT becomes capitalized (uppercase).

I'm referring to this [possible duplicate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/293912).

I'm trying to add :

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\figurename}{\MakeUppercase\figurename}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\tablename}{\MakeUppercase\tablename}{}{}
```

It worked for the ToC (the title was uppercased), but didn't work for LoF and LoT. Can you help me?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newlist{ColEnum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[ColEnum,1]{label = \arabic*), left = 0pt, nosep, 
    before= {\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\RaggedRight},
        after = {\end{minipage}}}
    
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
    chains,
    matrix,
    positioning,
    quotes,
    shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{FlowChart/.style = {
        base/.style = {draw, minimum width=32mm, minimum height=8mm,
            align=center},
        startstop/.style = {base, ellipse},
        process/.style = {base, rectangle},
        io/.style = {base, trapezium, trapezium stretches,
            trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
            fill=blue!30},
        decision/.style = {base, diamond, aspect=1.3, inner xsep=1pt},
        arr/.style = {-Stealth, semithick}
    }
}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{cl}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lm}{Lemma}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definisi}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Contoh}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\rm\bf{Bukti}}

\renewcommand\tablename{Tabel}
\renewcommand\figurename{Gambar}


\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\boldmath}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\figurename}{\MakeUppercase\figurename}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\tablename}{\MakeUppercase\tablename}{}{}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{10pt}

\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}
    {}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\bfseries}
    {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\bfseries}
    {\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
\newcommand\dd{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\null\protect\hfill{Halaman}\protect\par}
\setlength\parindent{1.25cm} 

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}
\addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill{Halaman}\par}

\makeatletter
\def\ttl@mkchap@i#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
    \ttl@assign\@tempskipa#3\relax\beforetitleunit
    \vspace{\@tempskipa}%<<<<<< REMOVE THE * AFTER \vspace
    \global\@afterindenttrue
    \ifcase#5 \global\@afterindentfalse\fi
    \ttl@assign\@tempskipb#4\relax\aftertitleunit
    \ttl@topmode{\@tempskipb}{%
        \ttl@select{#6}{#1}{#2}{#7}}%
    \ttl@finmarks  % Outside the box!
    \@ifundefined{ttlp@#6}{}{\ttlp@write{#6}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter %

\pagestyle{fancy}   
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}


\begin{spacing}{0.1}
    \tableofcontents
    
\end{spacing}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
\end{spacing}

\mainmatter 
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\backmatter


\end{document}
```

Sorry, i have to include my unecessary code, cz i just copied this from my original work. As always, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

The name for the list of figures and list of tables is going to be `\listfigurename` and `\listtablename` respectively.

Why not just redefine these directly? e.g., `\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}`? Ah, I see you did indeed do that. So what's going wrong? A bit of investigation reveals that `\listfigurename` has reset itself to the non-uppercase version even though you did the redefinition. It turns out that the `babel` package is being clever and resetting the values at `\begin{document}` so it turns out that doing the `\patchcmd` that you did with the corrected macros to substitute will do the job. (Also all the other attempts to redefine things like

```
\renewcommand\tablename{Tabel}
\renewcommand\figurename{Gambar}
```

are in vain (although `babel` should set those values as you've chosen anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know if those should be `\listfigurename` and `\listtablename`

Comment: Can i have one more question please. If i do that to Bibliography (i'm using BibTeX) is it correct to type : `\patchcmd{\bibliography}{\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{}{}`

Comment: It would be `\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{{\bibname}}{{\MakeUppercase\bibname}}{}{}` (untested—but I'm pretty sure you need the extra braces to avoid messing up page marks), **except** that your use of `tocbibind` redefines the bibliography to not have that accessible from the top level. It looks like the name is stored in `\tocbibname` and isn't impacted by `babel` so try `\renewcomand{\tocbibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}` and see what happens.